# Swift: 'Dictionary' is not identical to 'Dictionary<Key, Value>'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to make a `Dictionary` in Swift that maps a `MKPointAnnotation` to an `Event`, where an `Event` is a custom class.

I have instantiated the `Dictionary` as such:

```
var annotations: Dictionary = [MKPointAnnotation : Event]()
```

And am attempting to add to it by:

```
annotations[annotation as MKPointAnnotation] = event as Event
```

Which according to the Swift documentation is a valid method. I've also tried using:

```
annotations.updateValue(event, forKey: annotation)
```

However both of these methods give the error:

```
'Dictionary' is not identical to 'Dictionary<Key, Value>'
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Not sure what your requirement for doing this dictionary mapping is but: This "mapping" would not be necessary if the Event class subclassed MKPointAnnotation or if the Event class implemented the MKAnnotation protocol itself.  Then, you could add the Event objects _themselves_ as annotations to the MKMapView and you will then not need to trace back to the Event from the annotation.

Comment: That's a good idea, however in this case not all Events are placed on the map, just the "chosen" ones, so I'm not sure which way would be most efficient.

Comment: Just because a class implements MKAnnotation doesn't mean it has to be added as an annotation.  Only add the Events you want to to the map.  The map only shows the objects that you explicitly give it using addAnnotation.

Comment: I get that, my concern is more about the resource overhead of making every Event implement MKAnnotation, when only something like 5% will probably actually need it. Though, this still may be less than a new dictionary?

Comment: If resource overhead is a real, validated concern, I would go with creating a separate custom annotation class that includes a reference to its parent Event object (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248405/dynamically-change-leftcalloutaccessoryview-based-on-the-mkannotationview-that-i/25265552#25265552 for an example) instead of this mapping dictionary which seems less straightforward to me.  Just an option to keep in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're up-casting to a plain old `Dictionary` when you want a `Dictionary<MKPointAnnotation, Event>`.

Change the following line:

```
var annotations: Dictionary = [MKPointAnnotation : Event]()
```

to:

```
var annotations = [MKPointAnnotation : Event]()
```

Then do an alt-click on 'annotations' and see if it has inferred the correct type, which should be `Dictionary<MKPointAnnotation, Event>` instead of the non-generic `Dictionary`.

Comment: Ugh, that easy. Thanks!